# Performance between CREATE TEMP TABLE AS vs INSERT INTO SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.6

I was wondering is there a performance difference between:

```
query 1: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table1 AS SELECT * FROM lookup_table JOIN ...
```

then

```
INSERT INTO dest_table SELECT * FROM temp_table1
```

vs

```
query 2: INSERT INTO dest_table SELECT * FROM lookup_table JOIN ...
```

My concern was, the lookup_table is accessed very often by different users and when I run query 2, most of the users need to wait longer to be able to retrieve their result. What I was thinking was to write the data into a temporary table then write it to dest_table  afterwards . Im just not sure if writing into a temp table with give a difference performance compared to writing it directly to the destination table. Im using mysql 5.6.

The reason why I need to write data from lookup_table to dest_table is because I need to create a report from it. Seeing how complex the query from lookup_table is makes it very difficult to create a report so I decided to move those data to a single table then just make a report from it.

Comment: Have you done any benchmarking yet?

Comment: all my tables are of type InnoDB. I haven't done any benchmarking. sorry

Comment: Unless the performance difference is hugely significant in terms of what other users experience you should use the second form. Otherwise you're introducing a timing window between the select and the insert, during which you might miss some rows that should be selected.

Answer (score 0):

You're concerned about the lockout time that's taken by the SELECT query that populates this temporary table.

The tables are implemented the same way, so the cost of creating will be very close to the same in either case.

You might be able to get it to go a little faster by creating your temporary table in the MEMORY access method, but I suspect the difference will be minimal; the work involved here is the SELECT / JOIN stuff.

You might be able to get it to go faster by making sure your target table has no indexes when you create it.  `CREATE ... AS SELECT` will do that.

You will be able to make it cheaper to create by getting rid of `SELECT *` (which yields redundant columns on JOINs anywhow), and instead specify the columns you really need.

But, your best bet is to figure out why you're creating this table, and see if you can deliver on those requirements by writing queries against the source tables instead. If you make those query operations efficient, you've saved yourself lots of data shuffling.

Comment: Hi Ollie, I updated my question. I used * to save some time from typing columns but it's actually more like this IF(col1 is null, col2, col3) AS REPORT_COL1